# Display records from another table in an existing GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

Here is an example of the problem I am facing. I have a table called Issues, which has the initial record information. Each record also has a category and some have multiple categories.

Issues

```
ID | Name        | Comments        | Date     | SubmittedBy
1  | Server down | Need assistance | 6/1/2015 | John
```

IssuesCategories

```
ID | Name
1  | Internal
2  | External
3  | Mobile
4  | Email
```

IssuesCatList

```
QID | CID
1   | 1
1   | 3
1   | 4
```

I am trying to display all of this in one GridView that looks like this:

```
Name        | Categories              | Date     | By
Server down | Internal, Mobile, Email | 6/1/2015 | John
```

So I want to place the category names into the a column of the gridview. How can I accomplish this? Can this be done with the SQL query or do I need to do this in the RowDataBound in the code behind?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="issuesView" CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="issuesView_RowDataBound"
    GridLines="None" EmptyDataText="No issues" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yy}" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmittedBy" HeaderText="By" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: @fubo That is dealing with one table, I am trying to concatenate my categories into one field where their ID matches the ID of the main table.

Comment: @fubo. It is not a dupe of the linked question, because that question loads a single variable. This question requires a concatenated string in the form of a column, not a variable.  But it is a dupe of the question linked in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  [ID],
  name,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [Name]  
    FROM #IssuesCategories cats
    JOIN #IssuesCatList list on list.CID = cats.ID
    WHERE (list.QID = #Issues.ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS NameValues
  ,[date]
  ,SubmittedBy
FROM #Issues
```

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) for the awesome STUFF expression.